# preventing someone from modifying src of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, ecmascript-5

I load an iframe with src = "" on user's site to extract native 
constants such as Objects, Array etc. But I don't want 
anyone(specifically the user on whose website i am loading the iframe) 
to modify my src to prevent cross-site errors.
I did some research and I was able to prevent src from being modified by -

```
Object.defineProperty(iframeElement,'src', {
    writable: false
});
```

But the problem is user can still modify using .

```
iframeElement.setAttribute('src', value)
```

How to prevent someone from modifying through calling methods?

Comment: You might be fighting a battle you can't win here. You don't own the browser.

Comment: Try the [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox).